# How to add a custom style sheet to a web application utilizing EWL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, enterprise-web-library

I'm trying to use Enterprise Web Library to quickly bring up a a web app and I want to add a custom style sheet. I'm not sure how I can reference the style sheet within the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your style sheet is located in the web app project at `Styles/MyStyles.css`. In your `Global.asax` class, override `EwfApp.GetStyleSheets` like so:

```
protected override List<CssInfo> GetStyleSheets() {
  return new List<CssInfo> { new Styles.MyStyles.Info() };
}
```

This code won't compile unless you've run UpdateDependentLogic *after* creating your CSS file. This is how the `Info` class gets created for your style sheet.